# Is there an easy way to get the POSIX shell to interpret numbers with leading zeroes as decimal?

Tags: shell, arithmetic-expressions

In a POSIX shell script, I'd like to use decimal numbers generated by `seq -w` both in string manipulations and in simple calculations using `$(( ... ))`. This breaks because numbers with leading zeroes are interpreted as octal numbers. I have come up with something like this to actually get decimal numbers...

```
for n in $(seq -w 0 300); do
    str="xxx $n"
    dec=$(echo $n | sed -e 's,00*\(..*\)$,\1,')
    ...
done
```

... but I wonder if there's an easier / more obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use expr instead. eg instead of

```
for n in $(seq -w 0 10); do echo $n $((n + 4)); done
```

Use this:

```
for n in $(seq -w 0 10); do echo $n $(expr $n + 4); done
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than generate 0-padded strings with `seq`, generate decimal numbers and pad them with zeros with `printf` when necessary.

```
for n in $(seq 0 300); do
    padded_n=$(printf '%03' "$n")
    ...
done
```

Hopefully, you know the upper-bound ahead of time. If not, you can use something uglier like

```
upper_bound=300
for n in $(seq 0 $upper_bound); do
    padded_n=$(printf "%0${#upper_bound}d" "$n")
    ...
done
```